# Virtual box head start issue, not able to start VM

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to use Virtual Box , I am able to create a Virtual machine, but not able to start it.

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The Virtual-box kernel modules do not match this version of Virtual-
box. The installation of Virtual-Box was apparently not successful.
Executing

/sbin/vboxconfig

may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and 
the PUEL version of Virtual-box.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 
VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver
doesn't match the version of the user.
```

And this the error message which VBox is giving:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu Studio.

The virtual machine 'Ubuntu Studio' has terminated unexpectedly during 
startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

I have tried running

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you install Virtual Box?

Comment: sudo echo deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib >> /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: sudo apt-get update

Comment: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1

Comment: Did you reboot after installation?  It may need a reboot after installing the kernel module.

Comment: Yes i did reboot